# Creating simple addition and subtraction program in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm new to ARM assembly, and I'm struggling to utilize the basic arithmetic. I'm trying to create two programs, one that adds two numbers and stores the result to a register, and another that subtracts to numbers and stores the result to a register. I feel I'm pretty close but I'm not for sure and might need a bit of guidance. With these two programs I'm assuming that the numbers are stored in memory. Here's the addition program:

```
.global_start:
_start:
    mov r0, #1       // Moves the first number into the register r0.
    mov r1, #2       // Moves the second number into register r1.
    add r2, r1, r0   // Adds r0 and r1 and stores the result in register r2.
```

And here's the subtraction program:

```
.global_start:
_start:
    mov r0, #1       @ Moves the first number into the register r0.
    mov r1, #2       @ Moves the second number into register r1.
    sub r2, r0, r1   @ Subtracts r1 from r0 and stores the result in register r2.
```

These could be completely wrong, but I'm extremely new to ARM ASM!
Any advice or guidance would be very helpful!

Comment: No, `r2` is a register, not memory.  Single-step this code with a debugger and you can watch register values change.  Only store instructions like `str` and `stb` write to memory.  Or do you mean the input numbers?  Yes, they're part of the machine code of the `mov` instructions, i.e. "immediate" operands, and machine-code can only run from memory.  Use a disassembler like `objdump -d` to see the machine code; the low byte might be `01` in the first `mov`, IIRC that that's where ARM machine code puts the immediate for `mov`, with shift-count bits being separate.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I think i might have worded this a bit strangely, for the purpose of the program I'm assuming that the numbers being added and subtracted are already in memory while id like to store the result to a register - if that makes any sense. Thank you for helping me thought!

Comment: Oh, well then you'll want to load them with `ldr` instead of `mov`-immediate.  Look at compiler output for a C program using global variables, for example.  https://godbolt.org/z/oGv3MWq4a / [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, so instead of mov r0, #1, i would start with ldr r0, #1, and then add them as normal? or should i keep the mov step as well and just load them with ldr first?

Comment: Nope, if you want to load from memory, you need to have some data memory to load from.  If you want to set a register to a constant contained in the instruction, ARM calls that `mov`. (And it's only available for a limited range of constants).  There is a pseudo-instruction `ldr r1, =1` to ask the assembler to get `1` into a register somehow, either with `mov`-immediate or by creating a "literal pool" nearby (between two functions) and loading from it with a PC-relative addressing mode.  Use `objdump` to see what it actually did.

Comment: Or look at compiler output some more, and note how it gets a data address into a register before loading the 2 global vars from it.  (Unfilter directives to see how it defines them in `.data`, and/or google more about how to define global vars in ARM assembly.)